# How to replace Postgres array elements using SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Suppose we have a Postgres table with an integer array column `xs`:

```
create table mytable (
    id bigserial primary key,
    xs int[]
);
```

Using Postgres 9.4 and SQLAlchemy 1.0.14, I want to replace a single value (for example `123`) in all of rows in `xs` column. What I have now is a raw SQL query that looks like

```
update mytable set xs = array_replace(xs, 123, 456) where 123 = any(xs)
```

The `123 = any(xs)` is just to speed up query as otherwise we would replace all rows not regarding whether the interesting value is in the array or not.

How could I rewrite the above query using the SQLAlchemy ORM when I already have `MyTable` mapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using the correct [`postgresql.ARRAY`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.ARRAY) type:

```
from sqlalchemy import  func

session.query(MyTable).\
    filter(MyTable.xs.any(123)).\
    update({MyTable.xs: func.array_replace(MyTable.xs, 123, 456)},
           synchronize_session=False)
```

Change the [synchronization](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.update.params.synchronize_session) as necessary.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!